Laravel Passport 401 Unauthenticated Error
I have an api for my software that an RPA process hits each day. It's been working fine, but all of a sudden on 5/24, the process started getting a 401 error. I have a team in India that's built the RPA process. What's weird is that when I use their oauth client and bearer token to hit the api through postman, it works fine. I even tried connecting to a VPN through India myself and still got the same result, although I'm not sure if that's a valid test. No code has changed and no server configuration has changed that I'm aware of. The server is managed through Laravel Forge and I have a request out to them to see if they have any ideas.  I've confirmed that the oauth token is not expired and not revoked, which must be the case if I'm able to use it to hit the same endpoint in postman.
Has anyone run into a sudden onset of 401 unauthenticated error in laravel passport? Any ideas on what I could do to troubleshoot?
